# Where can I find the GX12 Thermal Pipe

Tags: mass-effect-3

So this GX12 Thermal Pipe will supposedly make the Normandy safer under extreme combat conditions or something. I'm all for my ship being safer. I feel like I've scoured the Citadel up and down, but no dice. Where should I be looking?

Do I have to complete one of the many "fetch quests" first for it to be available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll find it at the Elkoss Combined Arsenal Store, located in the Presidium commons, and immediately to your left after leaving the elevator.

It's name in the store is actually the "E-Gel Thermal Conduit".

You can also buy it from the Normandy's shuttle bay with the requisition console under Elkoss Combined Arsenal (with a 10% markup).

Comment: In order to see the store in the requisition console, you must have visited the store in person first.